# Does the sequence $\{\sin(en)\}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, transcendental-numbers

Is it known if $\{\sin(en)\}$ converges or diverges?

Also, I have a more general question.  For almost every rational $r$, I think we can say that $\{\sin(rn)\}$ diverges.  Does that statement hold if we only assume $r$ is a real number?

Comment: Do you specifically mean $e \approx 2.718?$

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 7):

The sequence $(\sin rn)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges if and only if $r$ is a multiple of $\pi$ (in which case it is the constant sequence $0,0,0,\ldots$).

If $r$ is any rational-but-not-integral multiple of $\pi$, then the sequence is periodic but not constant, and therefore doesn't converge.

If $r/\pi$ is irrational, then values in the sequence are dense in $(-1,1)$ -- in particular there are infinitely many elements in $(-1,-\frac12)$ and also infinitely many elements in $(\frac12,1)$, so it cannot converge in this case either.

Comment: Incidentally, is it known whether $e/\pi$ is irrational?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: That seems to be unkown -- [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence#Algebraic_independence_of_known_constants) it is not even known whether $e+\pi$ is irrational (and $e/\pi \in \mathbb Q$ would imply that $e+\pi$ would be irrational).

Answer (score 3):

Henning Makholm's answer is perfectly fine, but if you like another approach, it is straightforward to check that $\{\sin(en)\}$ cannot be a Cauchy sequence, since:
$$ \limsup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left| \sin((n+1)e)-\sin(ne) \right|= 2\sin\frac{e}{2}\cdot\limsup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left|\cos\left((2n+1)\frac{e}{2}\right)\right|\color{red}{>}1. $$

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that if we consider arbitrary $s$ then the series

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin(sn) $$

Can usually still be assigned a formal divergent sum  in a way similar to how $1 - 1 + 1 - 1 ... = \frac{1}{2}$

Recall that $$\sin(n)  = \frac{e^{in} - e^{-in}}{2i} $$

So the series

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin(sn)x^n = \frac{1}{2i} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  e^{isn}x^n - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-isn}x^n \right) = $$

$$ \frac{1}{2i} \left( \frac{1}{1-e^{is}x} - \frac{1}{1-e^{-is}x} \right)  $$

Now evaluating at $x=1$ we find that

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin(sn)  =  \frac{1}{2i} \left( \frac{1}{1-e^{is}} - \frac{1}{1-e^{-is}} \right)  $$

For that particular problem then we  have

$$  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin(en) = \frac{1}{2i} \left( \frac{1}{1-e^{ei}} - \frac{1}{1-e^{-ei}} \right) $$

Answer (score -1):

You can use

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(kx) = \tfrac{1}{2} \sin(nx) + \tfrac{1}{2} \sin(x) \frac{ 1 - \cos(nx) }{ 1 - \cos(x) }
$$

When you put in $x=e$, you get

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(ke) = \tfrac{1}{2} \sin(ne) + \tfrac{1}{2} \sin(e) \frac{ 1 - \cos(ne) }{ 1 - \cos(e) },
$$

so

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \sin(ke)
= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \tfrac{1}{2} \left\{ \sin(ne) + \sin(e)
\frac{ 1 - \cos(ne) }{ 1 - \cos(e) } \right\},
$$
which is undefined, i.e. it does not converge.

Comment: Why is it undefined? If you want, the point is exactly to show that $\sin$ and $\cos$ cannot conspire on $e\mathbb{Z}$ to make that limit a real number. For instance, if you take $x=\pi$ the sum is just zero, while if you take $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ the sum is Cesaro-converging.

Comment: Read the comments. $x=e$ and $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm.

Comment: And so? $x=\pi$ is the first positive root of the sine function, but in such a case the sum is zero. Moreover, I do not get why you discuss the convergence of a series when we had to prove or disprove the convergence of a sequence.

Comment: Read the OP, the question is about $\{\sin(en)\}$, NOT about $\{\sin(\pi n)\}$...

Comment: I read it, I am just saying that your last line - "which is undefined" - has to be proved, it is not free to assume.

Comment: For the general question, the answer has been given by Henning Makholm.

Comment: True, but that is not known. It reduces to the question that $e/\pi$ is irrational. I will think about that...

Answer (score -2):

It does not convergence for all $e$ and therfore diverges. We can easily see this if we pick $e = \frac{\pi}{2}$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we now see that $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} n) =  0$  if $n$ is even. While if $n$ is odd, this is either $-1$ or $1$. This is not convergent and thus divergent.

Comment: I think OP means $e$ as in the magical number $e$ ($\approx 2.7182$), not just another constant.